# Modeling autocorrelation in Generalized Additive Models (GAM) with re-splines

Tags: r, time-series, generalized-additive-model, splines, mgcv

Related to [previous post for speeding up GAMM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12756/how-to-make-rs-gamm-work-faster).

After fitting a GAM with mgcv, the autocorrelation (acf) and partial-autocorrelation (pacf) of the residuals reveal very clear AR8 behaviors (pacf sharp drop-off after lag-8, acf goes to 0 more slowly at lag-16).

I tried to add this with the argument `correlation=corARMA(form = ~1|trial, p=8)` in the call to `gamm()`. While the original `bam` took about 5 minutes, the current call is still running after 2 hours.

In the linked post, and the mgcv doc mentions random effects can be modeled by splines with `bs="re"`, how would that work in the context of an AR structure?

Comment: Did you look at the pacf plot stratified by `trial`? Estimating the AR structure is computation-intensive, the more so the larger the value of `p` is. [Zuur](https://www.google.de/search?source=hp&ei=Nm2mWufDCouRkwXchIfgDQ&q=zuur+mixed+effects+models+and+extensions+in+ecology+with+r&oq=zuur&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.35i39k1j0l9.586.1288.0.3119.5.4.0.0.0.0.72.281.4.4.0..2..0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.4.278.0..0i131k1j0i10k1.0.YUdY6mwUOOw) advises against spending too much effort trying to optimize the auto-correlation structure. I'd suggest first trying with AR1 or AR2.

Comment: Yes, I did look at the pacf plot stratified by `trial`, which can range between AR2 and AR8. The aforementioned GAM-AR8 model failed after ~30 hours with error from `nlminb problem, convergence error code=1`...I'll try with AR1 this time.

Comment: I tried to run the same model with AR1. On 1/10 of the data, the same convergence error happened after about 1.5 hours. On 1/20 of the data, the fit completed after an hour. Does this mean I just have too many data points? Would using gamm4 or adding a lagged version of response as a predictor instead of modeling residual correlation be good alternatives?

Comment: A slowly decaying ACF is indicative of trend in the residuals; are you confident that you have modelled the temporal variation in the data adequately?